# Does CoD BO4 standard edition have multi-player and blackout included?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-4

I wonder if the standard edition on PC has both multi-player and blackout included?

Comment: Just to clarify @WLTitanium, your question was downvoted because it shows no effort of any research on your part. If you would have googled 'CoD standard edition' you would be able to see what that version of the game includes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Standard Edition on PC includes MultiPlayer and Blackout.

One can be confused with Battle Edition which only has MP and Blackout. Standard Edition has more content than Battle Edition. And Standard + BO Pass will basically include all content (but will give less coins than deluxe editions).

See: https://us.shop.battle.net/en-us/product/call-of-duty-black-ops-4.